# MySQL database change on button click html

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I am new to HTML, and im trying to do something very simple:
There is a "code" in Mysql database with a value of 100.
In the HTML page there is a place where you enter the code, and if its correct it loads the Value and shows it on the page (which is 100).
There is a button, when you click on it, it takes away 5 from the value and saves it in the MYSQL database.
When you refresh the page and enter the code again,it loads the value and shows: 95.

How do i create this?

Im having hard time with this.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is another necessary component - a server-side script to receive the request and interact with the database, which JavaScript cannot do from the client browser. This is often a basic PHP script which the browser sends a request to. The PHP validates the input, modifies the database, and returns the new result to the HTML. In the most basic example, the PHP script would produce all the HTML.

Comment: Not very complex, but your question in its current form is too broad.  Narrow it down to just one piece (e.g. ask us for a SQL query to do the update).

Comment: Im sorry but im also new to stack overflow, all i want is for someone to give me an exaple that i can try out
So i just found out I need to use PHP, alright, but what now.
All i can find on google is how to change names and other things about people that are in a database, but how do i change a simple number, thats all i want to know.

Comment: @MaidenJames it does not matter whether you need to change a text or a number in a database, the same principles apply. There are thousands of tutorials out there to get you started. We do not do tutorials here.